# ComboBox que atualiza os dados do banco

Tags: mysql, pdo, formulário, sql-update

Estou desenvolvendo uma página que irá servir para editar os chamados de suporte : abertos, pendentes e resolvidos.
Porém diante dos campos que criei no MySql não consigo fazer o update para atualizar o que quero.

```
<form role="form" method="post">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <!-- select -->
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Select</label>
                        <select class="form-control">
                          <option value="Em Aberto" name="status_chamado" id="status_chamado" id="status">Em Aberto</option>
                          <option value="Em Andamento" name="status_chamado" id="status_chamado" id="status">Em Andamento</option>
                          <option value="Resolvido" name="status_chamado" id="status_chamado" id="status">Resolvido</option>                          
                        </select>
                        <button type="submit" name="botao" class="col-md-12 btn btn-success">ATUALIZAR</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
```

Ele deve atualizar o campo "status_chamado" da tabela "chamados" que já possui o valor "Em Aberto" quando o chamado é criado, sem mudar os outros valores.

Tentei fazer usando a concatenação do PHP mas me perdi todo...

```
<?php                   
                  if(isset($_POST['botao'])) {
                  $status_chamado = $_POST['status_chamado'];                  
                  $cadastro = "UPDATE chamados SET status_chamado = ' " .  $status_chamado . " ' WHERE id_chamado = " . $id_chamado ;
                 

                    try{
                        $result = $conect->prepare($cadastro);                        
                        $result->bindParam(':status_chamado',$status_chamado,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $result->execute();
                        $contar = $result->rowCount();
                        if ($contar > 0){
                            echo 'foi';
                        }else{
                            echo 'n foi';
                        }


                    }catch (PDOException $e){
                      echo "<strong>ERRO DE PDO = </strong>".$e->getMessage(); 
                    }
                  }            
              ?>
```